# Running thousands of MySQL queries, crashing server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a stock update on our company website, and the query is as follows;

```
$count = count($stock);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{

    if(strtolower($stock[$i]['stockloc']) == 'retail')
    {
                if($stock[$i]['avail'] < 0)
                {
                    $stock[$i]['avail'] = 0;
                }

                mysql_query("UPDATE `xcart_products`
                SET `avail` = ".$stock[$i]['avail']."
                WHERE `productid` IN
                    (SELECT `productid`
                     FROM `xcart_extra_field_values`
                     WHERE `productid` = ".$stock[$i]['productid']."
                       AND `fieldid` = 5
                       AND LOWER(value) = 'retail')");   
    }  

}
```

Eessentially it runs in a for loop and iterates through thousands of products, updating stock levels. It runs fine for about 4 minutes, then things start to lag on our website, mysql seems to become backlogged with other website db queries that it can't run (they all appear locked), which then leads to the inevitable;

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the
>   error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

It doesn't seem to be a timeout I've upped the limit in PHP.ini to no avail. The query isn't particularly complex, however it does run several thousand times. Maybe as many as 5000+. I'm not sure what the problem is, as we ran a similar update system on our old website, and although it wasn't one I designed, it didn't have trouble uploading this many stock quantity changes.

I'll be happy to expand my question if further information is needed, but honestly, I'm at a bit of a loss even how to trace the problem.

The $stock array is an associative array which has the following format;

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [avail] => 55
>             [productid] => 17761
>             [sku] => AER-TOUCH-2100
>             [stockloc] => retail
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [avail] => 166
>             [productid] => 22653
>             [sku] => CAS-AER-112
>             [stockloc] => retail
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [avail] => 272
>             [productid] => 22952
>             [sku] => CAS-ANT-001
>             [stockloc] => retail
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [avail] => 5
>             [productid] => 22956
>             [sku] => CAS-ANT-005
>             [stockloc] => retail
>         )
>
>     [4] => Array
>         (
>             [avail] => 12
>             [productid] => 22958
>             [sku] => CAS-ANT-007
>             [stockloc] => retail
> ```

I have tried running a delay every x iterations of the loop, but I'm still getting the 500 internal server error message. Clearly I need a better solution to updating my table.

Comment: You're causing endless locks in the DB, because you're mixing write and read locks that escalate to table locks. Try sleeping your cron for a few seconds, 5 to 10, between every 100 queries, to allow other users of the table (like your website...) to actually catch up with displaying data for actual customers.

Comment: two things... do you absolutely have to do this in a loop like that?? its a real bad way to do things unless you must... and another thing... if you are going to keep doing things this way then you should look into locking the table for update

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes so essentially I'm hogging the database and not allowing other queries to run? I can add in a delay timer, no problem. This isn't a cron, though. The php script is iterating through a large array to run that query thousands of times.

Comment: @John Ruddell: If you know of a better way, I'd consider it an answer. I will look at locking, however.

Comment: @MartynShutt honestly I don't know how your system is setup.. but if you are updating stuff from the same time multiple times... i would try to do it with one update query... if you could post like 3 examples of the stock and price change I could try to do something for you.

Comment: @ John Ruddell: I've included the entire function contents in my question. I pass in a large associative array full of product ids and stock levels, and proceed to run the loop through the entire array.

Comment: `$stock` is coming from the result of another query? Can you post the query that generates `$stock`? You might be able to join both avoiding all your loops altogether.

Comment: What I would try to do is create a temporary table or a view that you populate with the data and a stock id or whatever the unique identifer is on the table and then just do one update with a join on the temp table

Comment: @John Ruddell: I've never created a temporary table to then do a single update using a join, but that sounds like a viable solution.

Comment: @Prix: it is, however it is then turned into an array and heavily manipulated, but I'll post more details on it.

Comment: martyn you should try it with a temporary table.. create one with the data (loop through and make a string with the data) and then execute the query once to create the temporary table and then join the table to your table you want to update and `SET table.price = temporarytable.price WHERE temporarytable.fk = table.pk`

Comment: where is all this data coming from exactly?  why is all stored in a php array?  (and definitely, try a temp table)

Comment: also... this link might really help you out... skim the whole thing at least.  PHP specific: http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/

Comment: @John Ruddell: sounds like a solution. I'll get on it.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: It's a stock management system, and it's having to pull in a lot of different feeds to calculate stock levels. The grunt work is done by a local script which creates the final stock file tallying up stock, which is then passed onto my server-side script to run an update.